# Mysql Counting the same value from 2 tables as 2 different counts

Tags: mysql

I´d like to count a value which exists in 2 different tables. But it should be displayed seperated like this:

[image]

Of course I can count it seperately. But I want to have it in one query in one result. Thanks for your help

```
SELECT `X1`, COUNT(`X1`) AS Sales FROM `table1` GROUP BY `X1`

SELECT `X1`, COUNT(`X1`) AS Purchases FROM `table2` GROUP BY `X1`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain, because the set of `x1` values in each table may not be the same.

Here is one approach using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select x1, sum(sales) as sales, sum(purchases) as purchases
from ((select x1, count(*) as sales, 0 as purchases
       from table1
       group by x1
      ) union all
      (select x2, 0, count(*)
       from table2
       group by x1
      )
     ) t12
group by x1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the counts from one of the tables, and then join that with the other table.

```
SELECT t1.x1, COUNT(*) AS sales, t2.purchases
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT x1, COUNT(*) AS purchases
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY x1) AS t2
ON t1.x1 = t2.x1
GROUP BY t1.x1
```

It might actually be more efficient to do the grouping in two subqueries.

```
SELECT t1.x1, t1.sales, t2.purchases
FROM (SELECT x1, COUNT(*) AS sales
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY x1) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT x1, COUNT(*) AS purchases
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY x1) AS t2
ON t1.x1 = t2.x1
```

However, if there are any `x1` values that aren't in both tables, both these queries will leave them out. The ideal solution is `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but MySQL doesn't have this operation. See [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) for a workaround. Gordon Linoff's answer doesn't have this problem. Or if you have another table that lists all the `x1` values, you could use that as the main table, and `LEFT JOIN` both of the above subqueries with it.